# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1+e^x}dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1+e^x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x(e^x+1-e^x)}{1+e^x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} x\cdot dx - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x\cdot e^x}{1+e^x}$$

I can't think of a way to proceed further

Comment: You have already dealt with similar integrals: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814357/is-this-proof-of-the-following-integrals-fine-int-01-frac-ln1xx-d . Just set $x=-\log u$ to find $\pi^2/12$.

Comment: Be careful when manipulating improper integrals. The first one exists while the last one leads to an indeterminate form.

Comment: Divide the numerator and denominator by $e^x$ and substitute $u=e^{-x}$. The result can be expanded using the geometric series and integrated termwise.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700659/computing-int-0-infty-mathrmd-x-fracxex1-with-contour-integration?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thank you so much

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798895/how-to-find-int-0-infty-dfrac-x1ex-dx

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$${x\over1+e^x}={xe^{-x}\over1+e^{-x}}=xe^{-x}(1-e^{-x}+e^{-2x}-e^{-3x}+\cdots)=xe^{-x}-xe^{-2x}+xe^{-3x}-xe^{-4x}+\cdots$$

It's easy to see that

$$\int_0^\infty xe^{-nx}\,dx={1\over n^2}$$

Thus

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty{x\over1+e^x}\,dx
&=1-{1\over4}+{1\over9}-{1\over16}+\cdots\\
&=\left(1+{1\over4}+{1\over9}+{1\over16}+\cdots\right)-2\left({1\over4}+{1\over16}+\cdots \right)\\
&=\left(1+{1\over4}+{1\over9}+{1\over16}+\cdots\right)-{1\over2}\left(1+{1\over4}+\cdots\right)\\
&={1\over2}\left(1+{1\over4}+{1\over9}+{1\over16}+\cdots\right)\\
&={\pi^2\over12}
\end{align}$$